# A singular noun that is modified by a plural expression

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, nouns

Can you tell me which one is modified and which one that modifies

> A good knowledge of three languages **is** needed for the job

Someone gave this example when she told me that when I have a singular noun that's modified by a plural, the verb that comes after it is singular, but I still don't understand. I also need to know whether that sentence can be written as:

> A good three languages knowledge **is** needed for the job.

Like when we treat plural as singular:

> Thirty miles is a long way to run [*Oxford Grammar*].

Comment: Your version is not idiomatic English.

Comment: See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305389/is-the-superlative-adjective-of-a-plural-noun-singular-or-plural In which a plural modifies a phrase that looks like an adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A good knowledge of three languages is needed for the job.

The above example is fine.  The verb *is* agrees with the subject *knowledge*.

> A good three languages knowledge is needed for the job.

In the second example, shown above, the attributive noun should more appropriately be singular and hyphenated, like **three-language**.

> A good **three-language** knowledge is needed for the job.

Comment: I disagree with this answer.  "A three-language knowledge" sounds very strange and non-fluent to this US English speaker.  I know that attributive nouns in English are a tricky topic, but a knowledge of three languages is not "a kind of knowledge called three-language" or "about three-language" or "belonging to three-language", so the attributive noun rephrasing sounds very weird.